# Spring DeferredResult setting result not resuming request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, long-polling, asynchronous

I'm experiencing some issues using `DeferredResult` with Spring, I think I misunderstand something about them.
These `DeferredResult` are used for long polling.

I have an application on which multiple users can be logged in, and which displays a list of items from a database. The same items are visible for all the connected users. Any user can, at a given time, select one of these items and interact with it, but then the other users cannot interact with this specific item anymore (say like an item is "locked" for the others as soon as someone select it until the user "releases" it).

Anyway, I'm using long polling to notify the others when one user "takes" an item, that this is item is now "locked", to update their interface.

Say I have for example a url for the polling like:
`/polling` and another like : `/take/{itemId}`

I have a web application using Spring MVC with the "old-style" XML configuration with the parameters for asynchronous processes:
`<task:annotation-driven>` in my servlet config, and more importantly (I think) `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` in the `web.xml`.

When a user calls `/polling`, the request is returning a `DeferredResult`:

```
private final BlockingQueue<DeferredResult<List<MyItem>>> pendingRequests = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

@RequestMapping("/polling")
public DeferredResult<List<MyItem>> poll(...) {
    final DeferredResult<List<MyItem>> def = new DeferredResult<>(60000l);
    // ... deferred result init like set onCompletion(), onTimeout()...

    // add the deferred to a queue
    pendingRequests.add(def);
    return def;
}
```

Then when a user "takes" an item and calls `/take/{itemId}`, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/take/{itemId}")
public void takeItem(...) {
    // ..marking the item as taken and saving it into DB..
    // and then, notifying the other pending requests
    // the item has been taken by someone
    List<MyItem> updatedItemsList = getLastItemsFromDb();
    for (DeferredResult<...> d : pendingRequests) {
        d.setResult(updatedItemsList);
    }
}
```

Note that in the `updatedItemsList` list, the specific is now marked as "taken".

So here it is, this seems to work fine that way. Immediately after setting result on each items, the corresponding request resumes and "breaks" the long polling process without waiting for the request timeout so that the front javascript can update the list and make a new long request.

The problem is that I recently tried to "convert" this web application by using Spring Boot, and all the "Java/annotation-based" configuration.
And this behavior does not work anymore. Indeed, it's like **setting the  `DeferredResult` (in the `for` loop in the 2nd request) does not trigger the requests to resume anymore, and it has to wait for the timeout to return the result.**

However, I found that calling the `setResult` method on the `DeferredResult` objects in a `TaskExecutor` for example, makes everything work like before.

My question is, why ? Why does this work fine with the XML-style configuration, without any executor or explicit background  `setResult()` call, and this does not work anymore with the Java based configuration ?
Did I miss something ?

FYI, the Java configuration is rather "classic", I set `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@EnableAsync`, extends from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Thanks in advance for reading this and taking time to reply !